# Частота обращений к VK API

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Обращаюсь к VK API раз в секунду, пишу несколько сообщений подряд боту (быстро), и получаю эксепшн: `ApiTooManyException: Too many requests per second (6): Too many requests per second`.
Да, понятно, что мои сообщения слишком часто отправляются, но ведь не приложение же это делает, оно раз в секунду обращается, а допустимая частота - 5 обращений в секунду. Так в чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, на момент написания вопроса я использовал устаревший longpoll-сервер, который был плохо применим в нужной мне тогда ситуации. 
Допустимая частота обращений к VK API является именно такой, как и описано у них в документации, а ошибка была из-за ошибки в логике.

Comment: не советую сейчас делать приложения для VK на методах messages. у них в планах серьезно ограничить, если вообще не исключить этот блок из своего API, как уже произошло с audio.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov можно конкретнее, откуда информация об этом? У меня на сервере сейчас функционирует несколько ботов для сообществ в ВК, и не очень хотелось бы, чтобы всё это дело прахом пошло. А о нововведении о запрете требований на подписку и прочего уже видел сегодня.

Comment: прекрасно вас понимаю. информация скажем так, из конфиденциальных источников (ввиду схожей сферы деятельности). по поводу переписки сообществ пока данных нет, но будут резать переписку по обычным пользователям. да и в целом, если вы работаете с API VK не первый год, думаю уже чувствуете (по ряду изменений) куда ведет политика Mail.Ru Group. в лучше случае API превратится в что-то урезанное, типа Facebook Graph API, в крайнем - будет Instagram (когда реальный способ получить оттуда данные - только по Private API).

Comment: В общем совет, запасайтесь прокси, аккаунтами приложений и изучайте реверсинг.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov с этим я прекрасно знаком - работал с закрытым API вк очень много - как с голосовыми сообщениями, историями, так и с аудио после его закрытия :)

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov могу ли я вам в ВК написать, парочку вопросов по этой теме задать, если вы не против, конечно же?

Comment: это отлично)) точно пригодится) кстати, какие там сейчас лимиты на публикацию сообщений? как обходите капчу?

Comment: да, конечно, пишите https://vk.com/dmitry.maslennikov

Answer (score 0):

Из [официальной документации](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests?f=3.%20%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

> ### 3. Ограничения и рекомендации
>
> #### 3.1. Частотные ограничения
>
> К методам API ВКонтакте (за исключением методов из секций **secure** и **ads**) можно обращаться не чаще 3 раз в секунду. Если логика Вашего приложения подразумевает вызов нескольких методов подряд, имеет смысл обратить внимание на метод **execute**. Он позволяет совершить до 25 обращений к разным методам в рамках одного запроса.
>
> Для методов секции **ads** действуют собственные ограничения, ознакомиться с ними Вы можете на [этой странице](https://vk.com/dev/ads_limits).
>
> Максимальное число обращений к серверным (**secure**) методам зависит от числа пользователей, установивших приложение. Если приложение установило меньше 10 000 человек, то можно совершать 5 запросов в секунду, до 100 000 — 8 запросов, до 1 000 000 — 20 запросов, больше 1 млн. — 35 запросов в секунду.
>
> Если Вы превысите частотное ограничение, сервер вернет ошибку с кодом `6: "Too many requests per second."`.
>
> #### 3.2. Количественные ограничения
>
> Помимо ограничений на частоту обращений, существуют и количественные ограничения на вызов однотипных методов. По понятным причинам, мы не предоставляем информацию о точных лимитах.
>
> После превышения количественного лимита доступ к конкретному методу может требовать ввода капчи (см. **captcha_error**), а также может быть временно ограничен (в таком случае сервер не возвращает ответ на вызов конкретного метода, но без проблем обрабатывает любые другие запросы).

Comment: Вы внимательно вопрос прочитали? Я усыпляю поток на секунду, он априори не может обращаться к апи чаще.

Comment: Ну, значит, где-то дыра в Вашей логике и он обращается к апи чаще.

Comment: Где может быть дыра в алгоритме, длиной в три строчки? `Цикл for -> усыпление потока -> обращение к апи -> повтор цикла`.

Comment: Вы пишете: "раз в секунду (Thread.sleep(1000)), пишу несколько сообщений подряд ".
Несколько сообщений подряд - сколько? Они не разделены интервалом в секунду?

Comment: Вы, видимо, не понимаете. Я пишу сообщения боту, я могу отправлять их сколько угодно в секунду, но бот отправляет запросы апи только раз в секунду.

Comment: Например: `for (;;) {Thread.sleep(1000); lastMsg = new JSONObject(vk.messages().getDialogs(GroupActor).execute()).getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("message").getString("body");}` Программа входит в цикл -> спит секунду -> выполняет запрос `vk.messages().getDialogs(GroupActor).execute()` -> цикл повторяется, пока программа не будет закрыта, либо не вылезет эксепшн. Так понятнее? Но почему-то, если сообщений было много отправлено боту, он хоть и обрабатывает их раз в секунду, но эксепшн вылезает.

Comment: Ну я хз, но очень сомневаюсь, что проблема в api vk.
А несколько потоков не создается?
Попробуйте использовать TimeUnit вместо Thread.sleep

Comment: Ну, потоков будет несколько, не думаю что это что-то изменит, ругается ведь не Java, а Api :)

Comment: Почему не изменит?
Имеется api token, по которому вычисляется количество обращений в сек. Несколько потоков - несколько обращений. Несколько обращений > 3 = exception

Comment: Вы предлагаете разные токены использовать? Возможно, слегка это поможет, но если будут обращаться 10000 пользователей одновременно?

Comment: Нет, я только предположил в чем может быть Ваша проблема. А как в больших приложениях решается вопрос с доступом к апи вк - лучше поинтересоваться в другом топике у людей, имеющих такой опыт.